# Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Tags: php, httprequest

I am using HTTP request for sending data to the server. When I want to send the following error shows that I don't know how to fix it. I searched a lot on google but I failed...
Error :

> Uncaught Error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in
>   /home/test/domains/test.co/public_html/aminhd/send_data.php:4 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in

***send_data.php*** :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('http://server.co/adddata/');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'postman-token' => '7ecb7eb9-0273-a356-f84b-a56d9b035560',
    'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));

$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$birth_day = $_POST['birth_day'];
$marital = $_POST['marital'];
$marketer_code = $_POST['marketer_code'];
$city_id = $_POST['city_id'];
$national_code = $_POST['national_code'];
$identity_number = $_POST['identity_number'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$wife_phone_number = $_POST['wife_phone_number'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$field_of_study = $_POST['field_of_study'];


$request->setContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$request->setPostFields(array(
    "gender" => $gender,
    "full_name" => $full_name,
    "birth_day" => $birth_day,
    "marital" => $marital,
    "marketer_code" => $marketer_code,
    "city_id" => $city_id,
    "national_code" => $national_code,
    "identity_number" => $identity_number,
    "phone_number" => $phone_number,
    "wife_phone_number" => $wife_phone_number,
    "number" => $number,
    "grade" => $grade,
    "field_of_study" => $field_of_study,
    "services" => $services
));

try {
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

}

Comment: You are making  an object of Class `HttpRequest`, Make sure this class is required.

Comment: Two possible reasons... Either `HttpRequest` is not on your project or if it's in your project, your file doesn't know where to find it. You must `require` or `include` it. Are you using `composer`...?